# Epi, mono but not an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

In category theorie there exists the notion of *mono, epi* and *iso*.
In the category **Ab** of abelian groups we have 'mono $\Leftrightarrow$ injective' and 'epi $\Leftrightarrow$ surjective'.

We have the full subcategory of **Ab** of divisible group ie. an abelian group $A$ such that for any $a\in A$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ there is a $b\in A$ with $nb=a.$

Of course $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ are divisible. So we have the morphism (canonical projection) $$p:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$$ in the category of divisible groups.

The claim is that this is mono, epi but not an isomorphism (in the category of divisible groups).

1. *mono.* Let $D$ be a divisible group and $g,g':D\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ morphisms such that $p\circ g=p\circ g'.$ We need to get $g=g'$. We have $0=p(g(d))-p(g'(d))=p(g(d)-g'(d))\Rightarrow g(d)-g'(d)\in\mathbb{Z}$, so $g(d)-g'(d)=n$ for some $n$. How can we conclude $g(d)-g'(d)=0$? For $|n|\ge 0$ I find an $d'\in D$ with $|n|d'=d$. That is $|n|g(d')-|n|g'(d')=n.$
2. *epi.* Again $D$ a divisible group and $g,g':\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow D$ morphisms such that $g\circ p=g'\circ p.$ Let $p(q)=[q]\in\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. We have $g([q])=g(p(q))=g'(p(q))=g'([q])$, so $g=g'$.
3. not *isom.* Assume there is an inverse morphism $f:\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ of $p$. What is then the problem?

Comment: Why do you think it being a full subcategory implies that it retains those properties?

Comment: Well I guessed that this would be the problem. My thought was: Let $f$ be a morphism in divisible groups. Then $f$ is a morphism in Ab thus 'mono $\Leftrightarrow$ injective'.

Comment: But if you read the definition of being a monomorphism, then you should note that it has something about "for all..." and part of that "all" involves objects (seeing as it is a "for all morphisms" and these come with a domain and codomain which need not be divisible).

Comment: Thanks, I added some ideas in the question. Maybe you have a hint?

Comment: For part $2$, you should note that surjective always implies epi (this is a good exercise). And being an iso is indeed preserved and reflected when going to a full subcategory (again, a good exercise). So it is mainly that you need to somehow use that the only possible domains for the morphisms in the first part are divisible in order to show that the map is mono.

Comment: I added some ideas to 1. I can't conclude the claim. For iso: If there were an inverse map $f$ in the category of divisible groups then this is a map in Ab. $p$ is also a map in Ab. So $p$ is invertible in Ab that means that $p$ is mono $\Leftrightarrow$ injective. But the kernel is not trivial.

Comment: Why did you jump from talking about the existence of an inverse to something about mono and injective?

Comment: For part $3$, it's easy: $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ has torsion elements, whereas $\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't.

Comment: If $f:A\rightarrow B$ has an inverse $g:B\rightarrow A$, then $f$ is mono: for functions $h,h':U\rightarrow A$ with $f\circ h= f\circ h'$ we have $g\circ f\circ h=g\circ f\circ h'\Rightarrow id\circ h=id\circ h'\Rightarrow h=h'$.

Comment: @Andrei.B So where is the problem?

Comment: They can't be isomorphic. Let's say $x=\dfrac{1}{2} \ mod\ \mathbb Z\neq 0$ and you have $f$ your isomorphism. So you have $2f(x)=f(x)+f(x)=f(x+x)=f(1)=0$ but in $\mathbb Q$ if $2f(x)=0$ it implies $f(x)=0$ so it can't be injective. A divisible group ismorphism is an abelian group isomorphism, so it should be injective, but it is not.

Comment: Thanks! So indeed only #1 is left. You have an idea? I also feel not very confortable with: Why is a mono of divisible groups not injective since is holds for Ab? I thought I got it but no...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's my proof for $p$ being a mono:

So assume you have $f, g$ such that $p\circ f=p\circ g$ where $D$ is their domain, a divisible group. So for every $x\in D$ you have $f(x)-g(x)\in \mathbb{Z}$.
Now take $x\in D$ and suppose $n=f(x)-g(x)\neq 0$. Now take $p$ a prime which doesn't divide $n$ and $y\in D$ such that $py=x$. You get:
$$n=p(f(y)-g(y))$$
since $f(y)-g(y)\in \mathbb Z$ it would imply that $p$ divides $n$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Super! Where du you need $n>0$?

Comment: Well, my defintion of divisible group is with $n>0$, but I don't think it's that important.

Comment: Yes, but you use this definition for $p$, not for $n$. And $p$ is always $>0$ as it is a prime.

Comment: Well, seems I'm doing mistake severywhere today. I edited it out. Indeed you don't need it.

Comment: Haha, not it is perfect. Maybe you have an answer to the 'Why is a mono of divisible groups not injective since is holds for Ab?' question?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. If you consider $Id:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$, it is an injective morphism of divisible groups, but injective implies mono, no?

Comment: But your map Id is mono isn't it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48405/discussion-between-andrei-b-and-user114179).